# How to find and return the names of all images containing specific metadata?

Tags: command-line, find, metadata, tag, exiftool

I want to find all .jpg files in my directory that contain a specific tag and copy them to a different directory. In particular, I am using GThumb which allows me to put tags to my photos - it stores them as a list under Keywords: `exiftool -Keywords IMG_0205.JPG`
outputs
`Keywords    : winter, nice_photos, my_anther_tag`.
And I want to find all images containing the tag "winter" and copy them to another directory. However, I found no way how to specify that I want to list file names of only those images containing the tag "winter". I tried also to use `jhead`, but having the same problem, or combine it with grep and then sed but it seems too complicated (as I even don't know how to at least list the file name in the same line as Keyword: winter,...).

Do you have any advice on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a SMOP (Simple Matter Of Programming).

Use `find` and `xargs` (Read `man find xargs`) to pass a list of all the `.jpg` files to a `bash` script.

In the script, step through the list of files with the

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
    file="$1"
    shift
    ...
    do something with "$file"
    ...
done
```

construction.

In the "do something with "$file""  part, use `exiftool` to extract the property you want, test it, and move (or not) "$file", or just `printf` the names of qualified files.